# Disable hover effect on v-checkbox in Vuetify 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

When hovering over a v-checkbox in Vuetify 2, a darkened circle appears behind the checkbox. I would like to make this not appear. Currently, my v-checkbox is wrapped in a v-tab and a v-tooltip. I doubt that matters, but it is possible.

```
<v-tab v-for="tab in myTabList" :key="tab">
  <span>{{$t(tab)}}</span>
  <v-tooltip bottom>
    <template #activator="{ on }">
      <span v-on="on">
        <v-checkbox @click.stop/>
      </span>
    </template>
    <span>Tooltip text</span>
  </v-tooltip>
</v-tab>
```

I tried wrapping it in a v-hover and using the disabled prop, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the ripple effect, you can turn it off using the [`:ripple`](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-checkbox/#props-ripple) prop:

```html
<v-checkbox
  :ripple="false"
  ...
/>
```

Here it is in a snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      myTabList: [1, 2, 3]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <v-tab v-for="tab in myTabList" :key="tab">
          <span>{{tab}}</span>
          <v-tooltip bottom>
            <template #activator="{ on }">
              <span v-on="on">
                <v-checkbox @click.stop :ripple="false"/>
              </span>
            </template>
            <span>Tooltip text</span>
          </v-tooltip>
        </v-tab>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thank you!